# .Net MAUI 7, Consume API, Get and Get By ID methods are fine but return 405, Method Not Allow for Post, Put and Delete

Tags: .net, api, rest, maui

I have existing api controller for web and MAUI. Consuming from web client is fine, but with MAUI Get and Get by id methods are ok but Post, Put and Delete functions return 405 error.

Web Controller with No Authorization

```
        //[Authorize]
        [Route("api/System/GetSsC09EVideoType")]
        [HttpGet]
        public IHttpActionResult GETSsC09EVideoType()
        {
            IList<SsC09EVideoType> entity = SsC09EVideoTypeModel.SaCLSsC09EVideoType();
            return Ok(entity);
        }
        [Route("api/System/GetSsC09EVideoTypeByID")]
        [HttpGet]
        public IHttpActionResult GETSsC09EVideoTypeByID(int SID)
        {
            SsC09EVideoType entity = SsC09EVideoTypeModel.ReCLSsC09EVideoType(SID);
            return Ok(entity);
        }
        [Route("api/System/PostSsC09EVideoType")]
        [HttpPost]
        public IHttpActionResult POSTSsC09EVideoType([FromBody] SsC09EVideoType mySsC09EVideoType)       
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            int count = SsC09EVideoTypeModel.InSsC09EVideoType(mySsC09EVideoType);
            return Ok(count);
        }
        [Route("api/System/PutSsC09EVideoType")]
        [HttpPut]
        public IHttpActionResult PUTSsC09EVideoType(int SID, [FromBody] SsC09EVideoType mySsC09EVideoType)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }
            bool isUpdate = SsC09EVideoTypeModel.UpSsC09EVideoType(mySsC09EVideoType, SID);
            return Ok(isUpdate);
        }
        [Route("api/System/DeleteSsC09EVideoType")]
        [HttpDelete]
        public IHttpActionResult DELETESsC09EVideoType(int SID)
        {
            bool isDelete = SsC09EVideoTypeModel.DeSsC09EVideoType(SID);
            return Ok(isDelete);
        }
```

Working code for Get by ID method

```
public static async Task<SsC09EVideoType> ReCLSsC09EVideoType(string myToken, int SID)
        {
            using (Global.client = new HttpClient())
            {
                Global.client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                Global.client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", myToken);
                Global.client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("APIKey", Global.APIKey);
                try
                {
                    SsC09EVideoType myobj = null;
                    HttpResponseMessage response = await Global.client.GetAsync(Global.BaseUrlAddress + "api/System/GetSsC09EVideoTypeByID?SID=" + SID);
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        myobj = response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<SsC09EVideoType>().Result;
                        return myobj;
                    }
                    
                    return myobj;
                }
            }
          
        }
```

But for post and others functions return StatusCode: 405, ReasonPhrase: 'Method Not Allowed'

```
public static async Task<int> InSsC09EVideoType(string myToken, SsC09EVideoType myCl)
        {
            using (Global.client = new HttpClient())
            {
                Global.client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                Global.client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", myToken);
                Global.client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("APIKey", Global.APIKey);
                int sid = -1;
                try
                {                    
                    HttpResponseMessage response = await Global.client.PostAsJsonAsync(Global.BaseUrlAddress + "api/System/PostSsC09EVideoType", myCl);
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        sid = response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<int>().Result;
                        return sid;
                    }                   
                    return sid;
                }               
            }           
        }
```

Try from MAUI 7 Documentation as follow, also same return 405.

```
public static async Task<int> InSsC09EVideoType(string myToken, SsC09EVideoType myCl)
     {
           using (Global.client = new HttpClient())
           {
                Global.client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                Global.client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", myToken);
                Global.client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("APIKey", Global.APIKey);

                Uri uri = new Uri(string.Format(Global.BaseUrlAddress + "api/System/PostSsC09EVideoType", string.Empty));
                JsonSerializerOptions _serializerOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions
                {
                    PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase,
                    WriteIndented = true
                };
                int sid = -1;
                try
                {
                    string json = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize<SsC09EVideoType>(myCl, _serializerOptions);
                    StringContent content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");                    
                    HttpResponseMessage response = await Global.client.PostAsync(uri,content);
                    return sid;
                }              
            }           
        }
```

Testing with another HttpRequestMessage also 405 return

```
Uri uri = new Uri(string.Format(Global.BaseUrlAddress + "api/System/PostSsC09EVideoType", string.Empty)); 
HttpRequestMessage message = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, uri);
message.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");
message.Headers.Add("APIKey", "123");
message.Content = JsonContent.Create<SsC09EVideoType>(myCl);

HttpResponseMessage response = await Global.client.SendAsync(message);
```

I’m testing with local device(Android 10.0-api 29). Having problem with API Key Header.

Comment: have you tried adding an [HTTP Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#http-methods) attribute?

Comment: Yes, I tried adding HTTP Method attribute at api Controller. PUT and Delete methods are same return of 405 with Method Not Allowed. But for Post, return “StatusCode: 200, ReasonPhrase: 'OK'”, although it not insert new value and throw "One or more errors occurred. (The JSON value could not be converted to System.Int32. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 1.)" while "sid = response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<int>().Result;"

Comment: By default it shouldn't be the case but It may be caused by [preflight requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request) as well as CORS, you should check your server setup (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! Because of url format. My original format https://www.example.com/api cause 405 method not allow for post,put and delete. By changing into https://example.com/api solve everything.

Comment: Glad you solved it. You could mark your answer that may help others with same issue. Thanks in advance.